# Why passing firestore timestamp to ``moment`` gives the output as invalid date?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, momentjs

In my project, I am using moment.js. When I pass firestore timestamp to moment it throws the output as `invalid date`.

Here is my code:

```
moment({seconds: 1663679594, nanoseconds: 42000000}).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore stores Dates as a [Timestamp object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp). This is not the same as a Javascript Date() object. You have to convert it first into a Javascript Date object using the `.toDate()` method that Firestore has provided. See Sample code below:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

db
.collection('collection-name')
.doc('document-id')
.get()
.then((doc) => {
    const converted = doc.data().timestamp.toDate();
    const momentDate = moment(converted).format('MM-DD-YYYY')
    console.log(momentDate);
})
```

---

For more information, you may check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate).

Comment: Thanks for the help but in my case I am getting errors as ``.toDate is not a function``

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible code? `.toDate is not a function` happens when you're not using it on a timestamp object from Firestore.